# Почтут или почтят? Или,  может, будут чтить?

Tags: употребление-слов

Бегущая строка на центральном канале: в США почтут память погибших. . .

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я помню, возможны все предложенные Вами варианты, хотя "чтить, почтить" - глаголы 2 спряжения

Answer (score 1):

Кто любит труд, того люди чтут (пословица).

Глаголы ЧТИТЬ (относиться к кому-чему-н. с глубоким почтением и любовью) и ПОЧТИТЬ (оказать  честь, почет,  почтение кому-чему-н.) изменяются по 2-ому спр., но в 3-ем лице мн.ч имеют две формы: ЧТЯТ и ЧТУТ.

Формы считаются равноправными, но в настоящее время "ЧТУТ" используется чаще. Можно предположить, что этот вариант более удобен для произношения и поэтому вытесняет форму 2-ого спряжения.

Глагол "чтить" получен из "чьстити" от "чьсть".